# Math.floor( Math.random() ...) doesn't work with xml and as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

This is my code:

```
 stop();
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();

    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);

    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml"));

    var authorText = xmlData.Book.author.text();
    var random1 = Math.floor( Math.random() * authorText.length );

    function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    vraag.text=( authorText[random1] );
    }
```

But I get the error:

> Error #2007: Parameter text can't be null     at
>   flash.text::TextField/set text()  at
>   xmlflashwerkt_fla::MainTimeline/LoadXML()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

I thinks it doesn't work because of this line:`var authorText = xmlData.Book.author.text();`
but I don't know what to do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using authortext as a string in one place, in which it would have a length property. But I think you want to keep it as an XMLList object.

But then below you are trying to use it as an array that would have an index "authorText[index]".
Again, this looks like you want an XMLList object.

So try this:

You want to know the number of authortext nodes. You need to use:

```
var authorText:XMLList = xmlData.Book.author;
```

and not include the "text()" at the end, or you'll get a string, and not xml.

Instead, to get the length of an XMLList, you need:

```
var random1:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*xmlData.Book.author.length());
```

Note  the use of "length()" instead of "length"  - this is because xml can have children called "length" so to get the number of children you must call a method "()" instead.

So the whole method is:

stop();
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();

```
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml"));


function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data); // get the xml data
var authorText:XMLList = xmlData.Book.author; // get the list of author nodes
var random1:int = Math.floor( Math.random() * authorText.length() ); // get a number in the range
vraag.text=( authorText[random1] ); // display that node
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why this isn't working: go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
var newValue1 = verander.text;
xmlData.Book.author[0] = newValue1;
} I want to change a peace in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting a break point at authorText and see if it is returning null or breaking at this point. Also I notice that authorText and random1 do not have a Type associated with them. Try var authoText:String and random1:Number and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're waiting for the XML to load before you try to access data from it. You'll need to put those lines into the `LoadXML` function that you have associated with the `COMPLETE` event:

```javascript
function LoadXML(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    vraag.text = authorText[random1];

    var authorText:String = xmlData.Book.author.text();
    // ---------------------^^^^^^^ xmlData is actually loaded with your XML at
    //                              this point.

    var random1:int = Math.random() * authorText.length;
}
```

Comment: if I use you're code I get error #1009: Property or method can not be accessed via a reference to a null object.